# EXISTS cypher query with dynamic labels

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Given a simple `exists` query like

```
RETURN exists( (:NodeA {propA:{0}})-[:REL_B]->(:NodeB) )
```

how could I make the node label `NodeA` be queried dynamically? For example

```
RETURN exists( (:{1} {propA:{0}})-[:REL_B]->(:NodeB) )
```

but this doesn't work. I know that you can use `{1} in labels(n)` but how would I use it as WHERE clause in the EXISTS pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pure-Cypher query should work, but it is not performant since it will scan all nodes to find the appropriate `x` node(s) and cannot take advantage of [indexing](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/):

```
MATCH (x{propA: $0})
WHERE $1 IN LABELS(x)
RETURN EXISTS((x)-[:REL_B]->(:NodeB));
```

A more performant way to do it would be to use the APOC procedure [apoc.cypher.run](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#running-cypher) to execute a Cypher query with the desired label hardcoded:

```
CALL apoc.cypher.run(
  "RETURN EXISTS((:`" + $1 + "` {propA: $p})-[:REL_B]->(:NodeB)) AS res",
  {p: $0}) YIELD value
RETURN value.res;
```

This way, you can also take advantage of [indexing](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/).

Comment: I am surprised, so you say that Neo4j will not be performant with `WHERE $1 IN LABELS(x)` even if `$1` resolves to only one label? Anyway using apoc requires a plugin which is not that easy in my environment. I think I will generate the cypher with the dynamic label instead of using it as parameter which is a little bit more effort in SDN 5 but feasible. Thanks for help!

Comment: Noob question:  What exactly is meant by `$0`, `$1`, `$p`?  The `$` notation also appears in the [Neo4j Cypher Refcard](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/) but it's not defined there.

Comment: That is the current syntax for referencing parameters. The `{p}` syntax has been deprecated for awhile.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot use parameters in node labels. See https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/ for details.

> Parameters cannot be used for the following :
>
> - property keys; so, MATCH (n) WHERE n.$param = 'something' is invalid
> - relationship types like :REL_B
> - labels like :NodeA