# Multiple versions of the graph

Tags: cypher, gremlin, amazon-neptune, opencypher

Currently, I am working on an application that allows the user to display graph-related data visually. Users can then make specific edits on the graph:

- adding a link between nodes
- adding new node
- changing specific attributes of the node
- removing link

Those edits should be only visible on the "custom graph" edited by the user. Users can have multiple "versions" of the graph on which we added specific edits.

Is there any functionality in Neptune that could help us to achieve such functionality (we were also using Neo4j)? We can see it as having multiple views of the same graph with specific edits.

My current approach is to store the "edits" in a separate database (relational or NoSQL) and when the user wants to display a graph:

1. First, I fetch the unedited version from Neptune
2. Secondly, we fetch the metadata about user edits and apply them to the data before returning them to the frontend application

I would like to know whether someone had a similar problem and if you have thoughts about this solution. The solution may be similar to event storing - when we apply the events to get the final view of the graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your approach sounds reasonable. In some ways this is a bit like editing an image with layers, where the actual image is only updated when the layers are committed and flattened back into being a single image.

Amazon Neptune does not have such a "layer" mechanism per-se. So you will need to keep the edits somehow in a way that is managed by the application.

You could add them to the graph but with some token (like a property or ID) that you know is temporary and then delete them later if you do not want the edits completely persisted.

If you do not want to allow even temporary edits to the actual graph, then maintaining the change history in some other way, managed by the application, seems like the way to go here.

Comment: The first solution, which used Neo4j - was implemented by adding additional attributes to nodes and edges. However, as the number of graphs and users grows, this may become a maintenance problem. Especially that - for ex., once a month - we would like to update the initial graph dataset (we get a new dataset with initial nodes and links). At this moment, we would have to integrate those changes with "meta-data" added by users. We want to preserve the user's metadata.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to keep your custom graph separate is to use custom node labels (and possibly custom relationship types as well, if you ever search by just relationship type).

You could then alter your existing queries to pass in the labels (standard or custom) that you want to use. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56065847/974731) for a suggestion on how to do that efficiently.

Or, you could just use a different set of queries depending on which sub-graph you want to work on.

Comment: Yes, it would be a good approach if edits were mostly related to adding new nodes or links. Then, we could filter out what we don't want to see. However, it becomes more problematic when we modify the properties of edges or nodes. Then, the filtering becomes more complex. Complexity also grows when we have to update the initial graph dataset at specific intervals (say once a month) while preserving user edits.

Comment: Yes, I don't see a "simple" approach in Neptune, other than spinning up a second Neptune cluster for the custom data. And I should mention that a single neo4j EE cluster supports multiple databases, in case that is an option for you.